# Handlebars manipulating date format

Tags: handlebars.js

I am feeding the following date value into handlebars (this is ISODate format):

```
2016-03-04T11:24:25.893Z
```

However on the webpage the date shows as the following:

```
Fri Mar 04 2016 12:24:25 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

How do I keep handlebars from manipulating the date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myDateVarWhichIWantToPass.toISOString()` then pass it to handlebars.

Comment: I wondering that best approach is using helper registers avoid this ugly way to solve.